# Seeking a GMP binary search: How to compare two GMP mpz_t's using memcmp?

Tags: c++, gmp, bsearch

Motivation:  I want to use `bsearch` (binary search) to quickly search through a sorted list of 121-bit non-negative integers (they all have exactly 121 bits, although they may have leading zeroes).  These integers are too large to stored as individual `int`s, and so on, so I'm planning on making them `mpz_t` (using [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)).

Looking through the manual, GMP doesn't have a `bsearch` equivalent (although, correct me if I'm wrong), which leads me to:

> **Question**: Can we use `memcmp` or something similar to compare two non-negative integers with an equal number of bits stored as `mpz_t`?  If so, what is the correct syntax?

If this is possible, searching should be quite efficient.

I'm also open to alternative suggestions as to (a) data structures for storing these 121-bit integers that admit rapid searching in C++, (b) methods for searching through the integers that doesn't use `memcmp`.

Comment: Why would GMP need a `bsearch()` equivalent?  It seems to me that the standard `bsearch()` could be used with an appropriate GMP-based comparator function, couldn't it?

Comment: Hmmm... good point.  Indeed it could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're only 121 bit integers, why not use native 128 bit int extensions: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html ? That should be much faster, as you can avoid any "costly" operations like memcpy, all of your comparisons should be one instruction.